# How to make script Multiuser and single Autologin Load Test Useing Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, autologin

How to check Multiuser and single user Autologin Load test in my website..
I have studied the tutorial but I don't understand it. Below are the steps that I follow..

1. Test->Add->Theard Group ->Recording Controller
2. Test->Add->Config Element->HTTP Request Default
3. Test->Add->Config Element->HttpCookie Manager
4. Workbench->Add->NonTestElement->Http(s)Test Script Recorder

I set `Httpdomain name->adda52.org`, http sampler settings and add exclude patterns in Step 4 and then start. After that I set the browser setting proxy server and run login our site..
Everything is going fine.
Then I add view result and see that the result of each request is fine.
Then I pass a dynamic session value by using the following steps:

under `Recording controller->login page->add->Post Processer->Regular expression` extractor
add under reference

```
name                 salt (This is my session id)
Regular Expression         name="salt" value="(.*?)" />
Match No                    1
Default value =  session Not found
```

and then set this session value is my after login page like this : ${salt}
and run our script session value is showing on my post data.

**My question is**

1. Is my script is correct? if yes then

   1. After login I cannot see on profile page in Response data in View Result trees
      they are showng blank page ?
2. How can I make my script to auto login on multiple users and single user?
3. How can I check load on my site and where

please provide me step and how to check.?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tick "Follow Redirects" in HTTP Request Sampler?

To understand performing login better, watch [this](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication) video tutorial